# Setting date end parameter to 12 months ago

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, parameters, dateadd

I have to pull some comparative data and want to set the reoport to run automatically.

To get the first date range I use parameters

```
=DateAdd("m", -3, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

This is the start date 3 months ago i.e. 1 Jan 2013.

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

This is the end date, last day of last month is 31 Mar 2013.

I need to get the same dates for last year so I am using

```
=DateAdd("m", -15, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

This is the start date 15 months ago ie. 1 Jan 2012

What would I use to find the last day of the month 13 months ago, i.e. 31 Mar 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already worked out 31-Mar-2013, just subtract a year from that using nested `DateAdd` functions:

```
=DateAdd("yyyy"
    , -1
    , DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))
```

This returns **31-Mar-2012**.

Comment: Thank you ! so simple looking at it now.